# Why is one query extremely slow, yet identical query on similar table runs in the blink of an eye

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have this query ...which runs extremely slowly (almost a minute):

```
select distinct main.PrimeId 
from PRIME main 
join   
( 
select distinct p.PrimeId   from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId   or p.PrimeId = a.RelatedPrimeId    
where a.PrimeId is not null and a.RelatedPrimeId is not null  
) mem  
on main.PrimeId = mem.PrimeId
```

The PRIME table has 18k rows, and has PK on PrimeId.

The ATTRGROUP table has 24k rows, and has a composite PK on PrimeId, col2, then RelatedPrimeId, and then cols 4-7.  There's also a separate index on RelatedPrimeId.

The query eventually returns 8.5k rows - distinct values of PrimeId on the PRIME table that match either PrimeId or RelatedPrimeId on the ATTRGROUP table

I have the identical query, using ATTRADDRESS instead of ATTRGROUP.  ATTRADDRESS has an identical key and index structure as ATTRGROUP.  It has only 11k rows on it, which is smaller, admittedly, but in that case, the query runs in about a second, and returns 11k rows.

So my question is this:

**How can the query be so much slower on one table than another, despite the structures being identical.**

So far, I've tried this on SQL 2005, and (using the same database, upgraded) SQL 2008 R2.  Two of us have independently obtained the same results, restoring the same backup to two different computers.

Other details:

- the bit inside the brackets runs in less than a second, even in the slow query
- there's a possible clue in the execution plan, which I don't understand.  Here's part of it, with a suspicious 320,000,000 row operation:

[image]
[image]

However, the actual number of rows on that table is a little over 24k, not 320M !

If I refactor the part of the query inside the brackets, so that it uses a UNION rather than an OR, thus:

```
select distinct main.PrimeId 
from PRIME main 
join   
( 
select distinct p.PrimeId   from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId
where a.PrimeId is not null and a.RelatedPrimeId is not null  
UNION
select distinct p.PrimeId   from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.RelatedPrimeId    
where a.PrimeId is not null and a.RelatedPrimeId is not null  
) mem  
on main.PrimeId = mem.PrimeId
```

... then the slow query takes under a second.

I'd greatly appreciate any insight on this!  Let me know if you need any more info and I'll update the question. Thanks!

By the way, I realise that in this example there's a redundant join. This can't easily be removed, since in production the whole thing is generated dynamically, and the bit in the brackets takes many different forms.

---

**Edit**:

I've rebuilt the indexes on ATTRGROUP, makes no significant difference.

**Edit 2**:

If I use a temporary table, thus:

```
select distinct p.PrimeId into #temp
from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId   or p.PrimeId = a.RelatedPrimeId    
where a.PrimeId is not null and a.RelatedPrimeId is not null  

select distinct main.PrimeId 
from Prime main join   
#temp mem  
on main.PrimeId = mem.PrimeId
```

... then again, even with an OR in the original OUTER JOIN, it runs in less than a second.  I hate temp tables like this, since it always feels like an admission of defeat, so it isn't the refactor I'll be using, but I thought it was interesting that it makes such a difference.

**Edit 3**:

Updating the stats makes no difference either.

Thanks for all your suggestions so far.

Comment: @Ruirize: why do you say that?

Comment: 18K * 24K is 432M.  In the ballpark of 320M.  Might be a coincidence, but maybe a place to look.

Comment: Are you saying your composite primary key is 6 columns wide, and that the clustered index is on the PrimaryKey?

Comment: As already stated by Ray Toal, you seem to get a carthesian product.

Comment: If `PrimeId` on `ATTRGROUP` is indeed the primary key for the table, it can't ever be null, so why is that condition ending up in your inner `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @Damien... because it's a LEFT OUTER JOIN - and some of the rows on PRIME have no corresponding row on ATTRGROUP

Comment: @Mitch: Yes (well, it's 7 columns wide).  But this isn't the issue - I have about 70 tables with identical structures, identical keys and indexes.  I haven't tested all of them, but this query is only slow on this one AFAICT.

Comment: @ChrisA: I didn't say it was your issue. Every NC index will have to include that clustering key....

Comment: @Chris - yes, but your `WHERE` clause is restricting the result set to results where either `a.PrimeId` is not null (e.g. the left join succeeded, the value of `a.PrimeId` will not be null), or `a.RelatedPrimeId` is not null (e.g. the left join succeeded, the value of `a.PrimeId` will not be null). If your left join is restricted by `WHERE` to always succeed, it's effectively an inner join.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid idea, but: could that be linked to non updated statistics ? Did you ask microsoft support  ? (I know, I know, that idea is discouraging, but be optimistic, they might have done some progress)

Comment: @Damien... yes, you're absolutely right.  Thanks for elaborating.  I've now tried the equivalent inner join and that took all month to run as well.  The really weird thing, as I mentioned, is that the part of the query in the brackets (on its own) runs in less than a second, whether it's the original outer join, the inner one as you suggest, or the two left outer joins without the OR, or even the UNION that I tried.

Comment: If you want to know the reason for the performance difference, you should probably post two execution plans. You just mentioned the tables and indexes are identical, but that doesn't mean the execution plan is. I personally prefer the [STATISTICS PROFILE ON](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/sql-server/getting-an-execution-plan#ap-explain-mssql-tab) output, because it has the detail from all steps, not just the one you hover over.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience its better to use two left joins rather than an OR in the JOIN clause.
So instead of:

```
    left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
    on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId   or p.PrimeId = a.RelatedPrimeId
```

I would suggest:

```
    left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
    on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId
    left  outer join ATTRGROUP a2
    on p.PrimeId = a2.RelatedPrimeId
```

Comment: Yes, this is my experience too.  Your refactor here does indeed run very fast, slighly quicker, in fact, than my UNION.

However, my question isn't so much about how to refactor the original query (although I obviously need to do that!!), it's why it's sooooooo slow on one table, but not obviously slow on others of similar sizes and identical index structures.

Comment: @ChrisA, the makeup of the data is just as critical. For example, if RelatedPrimeId is always null in the faster ATTRADDRESS based query, then SQL will optimize out the inefficient OR portion of the query.

Answer (score 3):

I notice that the main-query isn't correlated with the sub-query:

```
select distinct main.PrimeId 
from PRIME main 
join   
( 
select distinct p.PrimeId   from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.PrimeId
where *main.PrimeId = a.PrimeId*  
UNION
select distinct p.PrimeId   from PRIME p   
left  outer join ATTRGROUP a 
on p.PrimeId = a.RelatedPrimeId    
where *main.PrimeId = a.PrimeId*  
) mem  
on main.PrimeId = mem.PrimeId
```

In this construction you don't need to use the 'is not null'  clause as well (will you ever need that since a primarykey will never hold a null-value?).

I was taught to avoid OR-constructions (as is already adviced by others) but also to avoid 'is not null' or 'in *valuelist*' - construction. Those can mostly be replaced by an (NOT) EXISTS-clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but if you have FK constraints referring from ATTRGROUP.PrimeId     and ATTRGROUP.RelatedPrimeId to main, then your query is equivalent to this much simpler one:

```
select PrimeId   from ATTRGROUP a 
union
select RelatedPrimeId from ATTRGROUP a
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason why one query could be much slower on one table than the other is that statistics on that table are out of date and it is choosing the wrong query plan.

However I support the refactoring that gets rid of the or clause that others have suggested anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've now updated the stats, but again no difference/